# Random, frequent crashes with NTFS errors

Tags: ntfs, crash

Computer goes dark as though the power was cut, reboots. No blue screens - no warnings. At first I thought it was the power supply and then a local shop tested that and said it was good. Memory test good. I changed out the motherboard and went so far as to install Windows 10 (originally was running Win 7 still) on a totally different hard drive.So I am now booting and running the OS on a 3Tb Seagate which also test good. But the crashes continue.

Will run well for hours and then boom, goes dark and reboots. Not a heat problem. I have reseated all the SATA cables and don't what to try next.

Error in event viewer is...

A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume ??.

A corruption was found in a file system index structure.  The file reference number is 0x9000000000009.  The name of the file is "".  The corrupted index attribute is ":$SII:$INDEX_ALLOCATION".

I don't know that this is even connected to the crashes and is maybe the result instead. Does this look like it could cause my issue?

I'd appreciate any suggestions and if more log is needed I will post that too.

Thanx in advance for your time.

Comment: NTFS errors like that is an indication the storage device is in failing condition.  Once you reach the point where Windows is detecting errors in the file system there normally isn't a solution to continue using the device itself.  All you can hope for is the device runs long enough to copy the contents, or you send the drive to a data recovery service, and they use their resources to recover your data.  Random crashes like you experienced can be explain by a storage device that is failing, Windows wants to access, and the inability to do so results in a crash